# Find what domain is using the old Let's Encrypt ACME TLS-SNI-01 validation method before the EOL on February 13th, 2019

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, domain-name, lets-encrypt

I just got this email. However, I host many wabsites (not all of them on the same server). I guess that one of the server is using an old version on the `certbot` client, but I'm not sure which. I however have a list of all the domains I host. Is there a command available to know which of them is using the old validation method ?

For reference, here is the email I got from Let's Encrypt on my contact email:

> Hello,
>
> **Action is required to prevent your Let's Encrypt certificate renewals from breaking.**
>
> Your Let’s Encrypt client used ACME TLS-SNI-01 domain validation to
>   issue a certificate in the past 60 days.
>
> TLS-SNI-01 validation is reaching end-of-life and will stop working on
>   **February 13th, 2019.**
>
> You need to update your ACME client to use an alternative validation
>   method (HTTP-01, DNS-01 or TLS-ALPN-01) before this date or your
>   certificate renewals will break and existing certificates will start
>   to expire.
>
> If you need help updating your ACME client, please open a new topic in
>   the Help category of the Let's Encrypt community forum:
>
> https://community.letsencrypt.org/c/help
>
> Please answer all of the questions in the topic template so we can
>   help you.
>
> For more information about the TLS-SNI-01 end-of-life please see our
>   API announcement:
>
> https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/february-13-2019-end-of-life-for-all-tls-sni-01-validation-support/74209
>
> Thank you,   Let's Encrypt Staff

Comment: maybe the package `ssl-cert-check` (debian, ubuntu) could help

Comment: Just update certbot on all your servers. That should take about a minute.

Answer (score 3):

I received the same email. After reviewing the information in a post titled, "[How to stop using TLS-SNI-01 with Certbot](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-stop-using-tls-sni-01-with-certbot/83210)" in the [help link](https://community.letsencrypt.org/c/help), they provided this command to determine if you need to:

```
grep '^pref_challs.*tls-sni-01' /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/*
```

They also suggested you [update Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) before running the command.

Answer (score 2):

I tested my domain name on this site: https://letsdebug.net/ (mentioned on the let's encrypt forum : https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/third-party-tools-to-check-your-configuration/76272).
I tested these alternative methods of validation (HTTP-01, DNS-01 or TLS-ALPN-01) and all my domains are OK.
You can already do this manipulation.
Best regard.